# JSTree Three_State and uncheck_node

Tags: javascript, jstree

In my project I want to uncheck a special node and its Childs when click on another special node (checkbox) The problem is, if the node I want to uncheck in three-state and not full checked, the uncheck_node method do not work for this node, only if the node is full checked.

```
   $('#html1').on('check_node.jstree', function(e, data){

        $('#html1').jstree(true).uncheck_node( 'j1_1' );




        });
```

Is there a workaround for this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `uncheck_all` that has worked for me with similar stuff in the past.

I believe [this](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=.jstree%20Event&f=uncheck_all.jstree) jstree resource may help. If my answer wasn't quite what you were looking for then you may be able to find something in there.